# Access level against user login criteria & hide the final message

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I have 3 forms in my c# winform app ,

- Login
- Data Entry
- Dashboard with Graphs

Now after login a user must only access data entry form , but after admin login he must get both the form access .How to do this .

For form opening i am using this ..but how to modify it i am not getting,as every time that "login not successful" is also showing

```
Data_Entry f = new Data_Entry();
f.Show();
```

And here is my login form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mechanical_Straightening_Dies
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ActiveControl = comboBox1;
            comboBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void Btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user = comboBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox1.Text;

            if(user == "ADMIN" && pass == "admin")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull as ADMIN");
                FrmDashBoard f = new FrmDashBoard();
                f.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            if(user == "USER" && pass == "password")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull as USER");
                FrmDataEntry f = new FrmDataEntry();
                f.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                textBox1.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                Btnlogin.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, when you log in as a User, you get both the data entry form, and the message that says "Invalid User Name or Password"? That's what you're saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as every time that "login not successful" is also showing

Its because the code does not end when the login is successful and continues to execute the remaining code i.e. the next if-else statement. You should add a return statement in your first if statment like this;

```
if (user == "ADMIN" && pass == "admin"){
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull as ADMIN");
    FrmDashBoard f = new FrmDashBoard();
    f.Show();
    this.Hide();
    return;
}
```

Also much better, you can just make it as a whole if-else if statement by making this line

`if(user == "USER" && pass == "password"){...}` to

`else if(user == "USER" && pass == "password"){...}`